# Adding elements to an array without arrayList

Tags: java, arrays, object

I am trying to define a method called add() that adds an object Fish to an array fish[]. How would I got about this without using arrayList? I keep receiving the error: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

```
public class Pond {
private Fish[] fish;
private int numFish ;
private int capacity;

public Pond(int capacity){
    this.capacity = capacity;
}
public int getNumFish(){ return numFish;
}
public boolean isFull(){//Ponds can only have so many fish
    boolean Full = false;
    if (numFish >= capacity){
        Full = true;}
    return Full;
}
public void add(Fish aFish) {// puts a fish in the pond--OR-- replaces a fish that has been temporarily removed 
    if (numFish < capacity){
        fish[numFish++] = aFish;}
}
```

Comment: I keep receiving an error with the given code

Comment: What error are you getting? It looks like the fish array has not been initialised...

Comment: the error I receive is: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

Comment: That error is because the array had not been initialised. Do it in the constructor and you'll be fine

Comment: @CarlDev an uninitialized array would mean throwing a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1):

Here dynamic array solution, which is a simple implementation of `ArrayList` method.

```
public void add(Fish aFish) {
    ensureCapacity();
    fish[numFish++] = aFish;
}

private void ensureCapacity() {
    if (numFish == fish.length) {
        int newSize = fish.length * 2;
        Fish[] newFish = new Fish[newSize];

        System.arraycopy(fish, 0, newFish, 0, fish.length);
        fish = newFish;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor for pond you can add `fish = new Fish[capacity]` to set the initial size of the fish array to the capacity of your pond. Remember you can not add values to an array only change the values already there.